# Extern variable define inside namespace LNK2001 Error

Tags: c++, namespaces, extern, linkage, lnk2001

I have been running into issues with these externally defined variables in C++ Visual Studio.

I have large data tables that are being compiled into code, rather than read. They are .cpp files defined as follows:

Table.cpp

```
namespace EX{
const int Var_Length=31;
const double Var[31]={31 Doubles};
}
```

In my same solution I have another class.h & class.cpp where I am trying to declare those variables externally.

class.h

```
namespace EX{
class MyClass{};
extern const int Var_Length;
extern const double Var[];
}
```

I have read through a bunch of posts but not have quite helped. Some suggest that they may need to be a global variable. I’m still quite a novice as far as C++ syntax goes but I haven’t seen anything that covers namespace external variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant variables have internal linkage. That is they can not be referred outside the compilation unit where they are declared.

You should write

```
namespace EX{
    extern const int Var_Length=31;
    extern const double Var[31]={31 Doubles};
}
```

From the C++ 17 Standard (6.5 Program and linkage)

> 3 A name having namespace scope (6.3.6) has internal linkage if it is
> the name of
>
> (3.2) — a non-inline variable of non-volatile const-qualified type
> that is neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to
> have external linkage; or

Comment: This language construct has not changed much over the years, so we would be amiss to not mention the canonical Q&A on extern. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. I suspected it had to do with the const type but I had not seen an example like this. This works. Kicking myself for not figuring that out!